# Potential causes of Ionic function not working in Ionic View, but working on web

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am building a food delivery app using Ionic. And I am having problems getting the app to work on mobile for the address creation step. After creating an account the user must create a delivery address, at which point the app figures out what delivery location to use.

Address creation works in Chrome (`ionic serve`) and in iOS simulator (`ionic run ios -l -c -s`).

However, once I've uploaded the app to my Ionic View iOS app for testing, it gets stuck at the Address creation step.

But at the address creation step, the Ionic loading wheel starts but it doesn't go away and there is no state transition to the menu.

Here is the implementation in the controller.

```
Address.create($scope.newAddress, $scope.user)
.then(function(response) { // never gets a response back in Ionic View
    console.log("address created");
    user.save(null,
        { success: function(user) {
            // success callback
        }, error: function(error) {
            // throw error
        }
        });
    }, function(error) {
        // throw error
});
```

The `Address.create()` method I have implemented is fairly lengthy:

```
...
.factory('Address', ['$http', '$q', 'PARSE_HEADERS'
function ($http, $q, PARSE_HEADERS) {

    return {
        create: function(data, userID) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var zipArray = ['1111','22222','33333'];
            var inZone = false;
            var restaurantCoords = {
                latitude: 11.11111, longitude: 22.22222
            };
            for (var i=0, bLen=zipBrooklyn.length; i<bLen; i++) {
                if(data.zipCode==zipArray[i]) {
                    inZone = true;
                }
            }
            if (inZone == true ) { // valid zip
                function onSuccess(coords) {
                    var limit = 3041.66;
                    var meters = getDistance(coords, restaurantCoords);
                    if (meters < limit) {
                        $http.post('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Address', data, {
                            headers: PARSE_HEADERS
                        })
                        .success(function(addressData) {
                            deferred.resolve(addressData);
                        })
                        .error(function(error, addressData) {
                            deferred.reject(error);
                        });
                    }
                    function onError() {
                        deferred.reject("Unable to Geocode the coordinates");
                    }
                    // GET COORDS
                    navigator.geocoder.geocodeString(onSuccess, onError, data.address1 + ',' + data.zipCode);
                }
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }]);
```

I've stripped out all of the code that I believe was working.

So a valid answer for this question could take multiple forms:

1. I'd accept an answer giving a decent way to debug apps **IN** Ionic View.
2. Or, if someone could provide an answer as to why it might be working in the browser and in iOS Simulator, but not iOS itself, that would be appreciated even more.

Comment: Ionic view doesn't support all the plugins yet. please take a look at this [link](http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/view-usage) for the list of supported plugins.

Comment: Thanks! This is good to know. So I can safely assume that the iOS Simulator is my best bet for app testing?

Comment: Device is always better (First Option). If you have a ios device and apple developer account. You can create and configure the required certificate with the device id and run the app using 'ionic run ios'. Second option is iOS simulator. Even if you use the simulator for the whole development, it is always advisable to test in the device before launcing the app. Hope this helps.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help! Please do submit an answer so I can give you the points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic view doesn't support all the plugins yet. please take a look at this [link](http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/view-usage) for the list of supported plugins.

Device is always better (First Option). If you have a ios device and apple developer account. You can create and configure the required certificate with the device id and run the app using 'ionic run ios'. Second option is iOS simulator. You can use the simulator for your whole app, though few tasks would need a device.

Even if you use the simulator for the whole development, it is always advisable to test in the device before launcing the app.